# bash sh - command not found

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/workspace/trunk;
svn up;
```

When I run `./build.sh` form command line, it says:

```
: command not found
```

And nothing happens. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `;` from the end of your script lines.

This doesn't happen in my bash, so I'm not sure what exactly is wrong, but my guess is this:

`;` is a separator of commands. Since your last command ends in `;`, your bash probably expects another command after. Since the script finishes, though, it reads an empty command, which it can't execute.

Comment: While the semicolons are unnecessary, they don't actually cause the issue given here -- worst-case you'd get a syntax error if you had two command-terminating sigils next to each other.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, probably. However, I don't know what bash the OP is using. Since the error didn't happen in my bash, my guess is that his version is different, possibly expecting something to come after `;`. The error message indicates `<nothing>: command not found` which implies his bash does in fact try to execute `<nothing>`!

Comment: Not necessarily `<nothing>` -- more likely, it's trying to execute `$'\r'`, which simply _renders_ as nothing.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, no the error message is enclosed in double quotes, most probably by the OP. There is one `"` in the end of the message also!

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. When a script uses normal (UNIX-format) line endings, trailing `;`s are harmless -- you can easily test this yourself. It's only DOS line-endings that make this error trigger.

Answer (score 58):

I solved adding execute permissions:

`sudo chmod +x file.sh`

Comment: Worked. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 19):

I Have resolved my error from this command.

```
sudo chmod +x build.sh
```

Answer (score 15):

My guess is that you have unprintable control characters in the file, or it has `\r\n` (CRLF) line endings (dos/windows mode).

Try checking it with these commands:

```
$ hexdump -C build.sh 
00000000  23 21 2f 62 69 6e 2f 62  61 73 68 0a 63 64 20 7e  |#!/bin/bash.cd ~|
00000010  2f 77 6f 72 6b 73 70 61  63 65 2f 74 72 75 6e 6b  |/workspace/trunk|
00000020  3b 0a 73 76 6e 20 75 70  3b 0a                    |;.svn up;.|
0000002a

$ file build.sh 
build.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable

$ unix2dos build.sh 
unix2dos: converting file build.sh to DOS format ...

$ hexdump -C build.sh 
00000000  23 21 2f 62 69 6e 2f 62  61 73 68 0d 0a 63 64 20  |#!/bin/bash..cd |
00000010  7e 2f 77 6f 72 6b 73 70  61 63 65 2f 74 72 75 6e  |~/workspace/trun|
00000020  6b 3b 0d 0a 73 76 6e 20  75 70 3b 0d 0a           |k;..svn up;..|
0000002d

$ file build.sh 
build.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: I'll bet you $5 that it's really build.sh, but kudos for biuld.sh example :D

Comment: I just used OP's filename :P Yeah, i bet it's `build.sh` too

Answer (score 11):

None of the above worked for me except

```
sudo ./build.sh
```